# Binding a function to Kendo MVVM data-template

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, kendo-ui, model-binding

I'm trying to port an example KnockoutJS I found over to Kendo and I'm having some trouble. It seems its not working as I had hoped. It looks like the key piece is the data-template="getTemplate" binding as shown below.

```
<script id="current-tmpl" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <h2 data-bind="text: name"></h2>
    <div data-template="getTemplate" data-bind="source: model"></div>
</script>
```

Where getTemplate is a viewmodel member function that returns the currently selected template name.

Here's my complete JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raygunc/vKBa8/

And here was the inspiration Fiddle in Knockout: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/FyuSD/

Ideally I'm trying to come up with a solution to build a "wizard-like" data gathering flow using Kendo SPA and MVVM. I will have about 50-60 different templates for different questions and I need a way to load them on the fly. This is where I'm starting.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I ended up giving up on Kendo for this more advanced functionality and built this using Durandal's containerless composition binding as described on this page. It lets you have an observable member that will keep a reference to the active view. This way when it changes it can rebuild the UI w/ the new template. ref: [link](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition.html)

Comment: yup i also spent a lot of time getting this to work PROPERLY, there is no easy way